# Pandas dataframe column split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing 3 columns.

This is what it looks like:

```
User History New
101  [X,Y,Z] [A-0,B-1] 
102  [Q,M,N] [A-1,B-0]
```

I would like to modify my dataframe to be represented this way:

```
User History New 0or1
101  [X,Y,Z] A   0
101  [X,Y,Z] B   1
102  [Q,M,N] A   1
102  [Q,M,N] B   0
```

How can I do so?

Basically, the reason I’m doing this is because I’m trying to create a model which predicts 0 or 1 for each element in new based on the the history.
Hence, I thought splitting them this way would make sense to train the model based on the three columns.

Though I was looking for ways to split the dataframe as described, I’m open to suggestions if there’s any other efficient way I can use the data provided (first table) to create a model to predict 1 or 0 for each element in array ‘new’ for the respective history.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at DataFrame.explode and Dataframe.melt

Comment: 1st explode using `df.explode` then use `pd.Series.str.split`

Comment: are the columns `History` and `New` lists or strings?

Comment: @Onyambu they are lists

Comment: Does pd.Series.str.split create a new column? @Ch3steR

Comment: Yes, set `expand` parameter to `True` i.e `pd.Series.str.split('-', expand=True)`

Comment: `df.explode('New').pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x, x.New.str.split('-',expand = True)],axis = 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = df.explode('New')
pd.concat([df1,df1.New.str.split('-', expand = True)],axis=1)
   User    History  New  0  1
0   101  [X, Y, Z]  A-0  A  0
0   101  [X, Y, Z]  B-1  B  1
1   102  [Q, M, N]  A-1  A  1
1   102  [Q, M, N]  B-0  B  0
```

Comment: Damn it, you beat me on time ;) just add a `.drop(columns='New')` to remove the initial column

Comment: Works well! Also, I can rename the two new columns right?

Comment: `df1.assign(**df1['New'].str.split('-',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'New', 1:'0or'}))`